# Fire async postback from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, postback

Is there a way to fire a postback to the server through jQuery?

I've tried just putting the postback signature in a .change method on a hiddenfield but it causes a full postback.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're doing. Some sample code might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post to the server use jquery's ajax/get/post method(s):
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Also, you may have triggered the full request because the .change function didn't return false.  Just a thought...